# undefined method `args=' for [[]]:Sass::Tree::FunctionNode deploying to heroku with rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, sass, compass-sass, asset-pipeline

I have an app that I am trying to deploy to Heroku Cedar stack with rails 3.1.0.rc5.
Some blogs that I followed implementing the migration to cedar and asset pipeline:

- http://metaskills.net/2011/07/29/use-compass-sass-framework-files-with-the-rails-3.1.0.rc5-asset-pipeline/
- http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar
- http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html

After a git push to heroku, I ran the assets:precompile task:

```
heroku run rake -t assets:precompile --app myapp
```

The js files are compiled fine, however Sass bombs compiling application.css.scss with error:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `args=' for [[]]:Sass::Tree::FunctionNode
  (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)
```

Full output and stacktrace here: https://gist.github.com/1122683

running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` locally executes fine without errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be some kind of incompatibility between Sass 3.1.6 and blueprint; I added

`gem 'sass', '3.1.5'`

to my gemfile and that seems to have cleared it up

Comment: @DucDIgital if you use bundler it is unnecessary to uninstall previous version of sass.